# Python3: return False on empty cell csv file

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that should only execute when 2 cells are not the same:

```
if row[72] == 'Totaal' and read_cell(74, (i + 11)) != read_cell(74, i):
```

The `read_cell` function:

```
def read_cell(x, y):
    y_count = 0
    for n in reader:
        if y_count == y:
            cell = n[x]
            return cell
        y_count += 1
```

However, when `read_cell()` encounters a 'empty cell' (essentally a list that does not have the requested index) it logically throws the error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

I am trying to only let `read_cell` return something if the list has 74 columns (starting from 0). One of the many things I tried:

```
def read_cell(x, y):
    y_count = 0
    for n in reader:
        if y_count == y:
            if len(n) == 74
                cell = n[x]
                return cell
            else:
                return False
        y_count += 1
```

However, this results every False everytime.
I know I cannot ask others to write code for me but I have run out of ideas on how to make that if statement work.

(note: there are empty columns in the csv file)

Answer (score 0):

I have read your post again. And I think I have misunderstood you. Sorry for that.

Is it possible that your `len(n) in reader` is bigger than 74? If so, you should use `len(n) >= 74`.